# HTTPs post request with headers test in jmeter and save the test result in mongodb and show it in grafana

Tags: java, mongodb, https, jmeter, grafana

I am unable to do configure the mongodb and jmeter setup to save the http post result in mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, are you aware of [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html), if you change the data storage from MongoDB to [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/) you will get benefit of simplified configuration as 99% of monitoring work has already been done.

---

If the Backend Listener is not something you can use be aware that you can store whatever information you want into the MongoDB via [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor), there is **prev** shorthand which stands for [HTTPSampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampleResult.html) hence you will be able to get such metrics as:

- [Elapsed Time](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getTime--)
- [Status Code](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getResponseCode--)
- [Status Message](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getResponseMessage--)
- [Response Data](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getResponseData--)
- etc.

Given you have [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you should be able to insert the metrics you need into a MongoDB collection like:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult
import org.bson.Document


MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://your_mongo_host:your_mongo_port")

MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("your_mongo_database")
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("your_collection")

Document document = new Document("statusCode", prev.getResponseCode()
        .append("success", prev.isSuccessful())
        .append("statusMessage", prev.getResponseMessage()))
collection.insertOne(document)
```

Check out [MongoDB Performance Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mongodb-performance-testing-with-jmeter/) article for more information on working with MongoDB from JMeter's JSR223 Test Elements.

Comment: I am using SOAP post request , Can I do test it in jmeter with mongodb and grafana